# Unmarshalling unknown type code when activity navigation

Tags: android

```
2020-03-17 17:58:36.607 14736-14736/packageName E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: packageName, PID: 14736
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packageName/cpackageName.bootstrap.tutorial.TutorialActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@5e986ba: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131362175 at offset 572
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@5e986ba: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131362175 at offset 572
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2943)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:3325)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2482)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3242)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
        at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1029)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:772)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2607)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:235)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:316)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.visa.wasabi.bootstrap.tutorial.TutorialActivity.onCreate(TutorialActivity.kt:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7698)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/21844945/how-to-fix-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-xxx-at-offset-yyy-in-android

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like androidx library's bug.
Did you find out how to resolve this problem or have any workaround solution?

Comment: Were you able to track this crash down?

Comment: did you find the solution. can you please share if so?